# shell script function return a string

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am new to shell scripts, I am trying to create a simple function which will return the concatenated two strings that are passed as parameters. I tried with below code

```
   function getConcatenatedString() {
       echo "String1 $1"
       echo "String2 $2"
       str=$1/$2
       echo "Concatenated String ${str}"
       echo "${str}"
   }
```

//I am calling the above function

```
  constr=$(getConcatenatedString "hello" "world")
  echo "printing result"
  echo "${constr}"
  echo "exit"
```

I see the below output when running the script with above code,

```
   printing result
   String1 hello
   String2 world
   Concatenated String hello/world
   hello/world
   exit
```

If you look at the code I am first calling the function and then I am echoing "printing result" statement, but the result is  first comes the "printing result" and echos the statement inside the function. Is the below statement calling the function

```
   constr=$(getConcatenatedString "hello" "world")
```

or

```
   echo ${constr}
```

is calling the function ?

Because if I comment out #echo ${constr} then nothing is getting echoed !!! Please clarify me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first is calling the function and storing *all* of the output (four `echo` statements) into `$constr`.

Then, after return, you echo the preamble `printing result`, `$constr` (consisting of four lines) and the exit message.

That's how `$()` works, it captures the entire standard output from the enclosed command.

It sounds like you want to see some of the `echo` statements on the console rather than capturing them with the `$()`. I think you should just be able to send them to standard error for that:

```
echo "String1 $1" >&2
```

Answer (score 1):

paxdiablo's solution is correct.  You cannot return a string from a function, but you can capture the output of the function or return an integer value that can be retrieved by the caller from `$?`.  However, since all shell variables are global, you can simply do:

```
getConcatenatedString() { str="$1/$2"; }      
getConcatenatedString hello world
echo "Concatenated String ${str}"
```

Note that the `function` keyword is redundant with `()`, but `function` is less portable.

Answer (score 1):

A more flexible, but slightly harder to understand approach is to pass a variable name, and use `eval` so that the variable becomes set in the caller's context (either a global or a function local). In bash:

```
function mylist()
{
    local _varname=$1 _p _t
    shift

    for _p in "$@"; do
        _t=$_t[$_p]
    done

    eval "$_varname=\$_t"
}

mylist tmpvar a b c
echo "result: $tmpvar"
```

On my Linux desktop (bash-3.2) it's approx 3-5x faster (10,000 iterations) than using ``` `` ```, since the latter has process creation overheads.

If you have bash-4.2, its `declare -g` allows a function to set a global variable, so you can replace the unpretty `eval` with:

```
declare -g $_varname="$_t"
```

The `eval` method is similar to [TCL's](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/upvar.htm) `upvar 1`, and `declare -g` is similar to `upvar #0`.

Some shell builtins support something similar, like bash's `printf` with "-v", again saving process creation by assigning directly to a variable instead of capturing output (~20-25x faster for me).