# grep text by function parameter in bash

Tags: bash

There is a file name as `pkg_list`

```
a-1.2b-1.tar.gz
c-2.5b-1.tar.gz
a xx-1.4.txz
a$xx-1.4.txz
中文-3.txz
xx-3.2-2.tar.gz
xxy-1.3.tar.gz
```

My bash function can input package name like 'xx'

```
pkg_find() { # <pkg_name> as $1
  grep "^$1-[0-9]*" pkg_list
}
pkg_find xx # wish it return xx-3.2-2.tar.gz
```

I know I can not pass $1 directly into pkg_find, what's the correct method?

[SOLVED]
In this case, because $1 is enclosed by double quote, I found even regex meta chars could pass as parameter.

Comment: Do you want the argument to the script i.e `$ ./script.sh xx` to be passed on to the function? then you need `pkg_find $1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing looks right to me.

What isn't working?

I tried the code in your question, and `pkg_find xx` displays ‘xx-3.2-2.tar.gz’ — which you say is the output you were hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* pass `$1` directly to `pkg_find`

```
pkg_find() { # <pkg_name> as $1
  grep "^$1-[0-9]*" pkg_list
}
pkg_find "$1"
```

In the main body, `$1, $2, ..` are the [script arguments](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters), you get from the command line or another calling script. In a [shell function](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions) they refer to the function arguments.

When you call this on the command line

```
sh pkg_find.sh xx
```

you will get

> xx-3.2-2.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Your code and your question seem to me to ask for different things, you want to either/both of:

- pass a function parameters: [Passing parameters to a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6212219/1955371)
- return a string from a function: [shell script function return a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11758368/1955371)

$1, $2 etc at the top-level of a script are the script parameters; within a function they
are set to the function parameters, or unset if there are no parameters.