# global variable value not set inside a function in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have two shell script like as follows:

**a.sh**

```
tes=2
testfunction(){
    tes=3
    echo 5
}
testfunction
echo $tes
```

**b.sh**

```
tes=2
testfunction(){
    tes=3
    echo 5
}
val=$(testfunction)
echo $tes
echo $val
```

In first script `tes` value is '3' as expected but in second it's 2?

Why is it behaving like this?

Is `$(funcall)` creating a new sub shell and executing the function? If yes, how can address this?

Comment: Yes `$(funcall)` creates a sub-shell. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951346/is-there-a-subshell-created-when-i-run-sh-c-command-a-new-shell-or-none-of

Comment: @damienfrancois how to solve this issue so that 'tes' should get the proper value as expected

Answer (score 4):

$() and `` create new shell and return output as a result.

Use 2 variables:

```
tes=2

testfunction() {
  tes=3
  tes_str="string result"
}

testfunction
echo $tes
echo $tes_str
```

output

```
3
string result
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution creates a subshell which will have its own variable that will be destroyed when it is terminated.

One way to counter this is to pass tes as a parameter, and then return* it using echo.

```
tes=2
testfunction(){
echo $1
}
val=$(testfunction $tes)
echo $tes
echo $val
```

You can also use the `return` command although i would advise against this as it is supposed to be used to for return codes, and as such only ranges from 0-255.Anything outside of that range will become 0

To return a string do the same thing

```
tes="i am a string"
testfunction(){
echo "$1 from in the function"
}
val=$(testfunction "$tes")
echo $tes
echo $val
```

#### Output

```
i am a string
i am a string from in the function
```

*Doesnt really return it, it just sends it to STDOUT in the subshell which is then assigned to val

Comment: is there a way to return string from a function

Comment: [shell script function return a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758368/shell-script-function-return-a-string)

Comment: @nantitv yes the exact same way